# Move many files around without confusing git's rename detection heuristic

Tags: git

I have a git repo of a larger Java codebase (~3000 classes), and I want to apply a large reorganization to the whole codebase which will move many classes to other places, rename them, and adjust the references in other classes accordingly. The actual code transformation is scripted and well-tested and I can run it in a few seconds.

Now when I commit the whole thing, git will show many deleted and new files, as the number of moved files exceeds some rename detection limit. That would make 'git annotate' useless in the future, which I would like to avoid if possible.

How can I do the reorganization, and still keep meaningful file histories?

Comment: The great thing with git is that you can try it all locally and see yourself what will happen. Even better than asking, is finding out for sure for yourself. I imagine it will just work. You can always try increasing `diff.renameLimit` and `merge.renameLimit`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When Git walks from one commit to another and compares the two trees, it puts all the "missing" and "added" files into pairing queues (which then determine how much CPU time and memory is thrown at the problem of dynamically recovering the renames from inexact file matches—exact file matches go very fast and shrink the pairing queue length and hence reduce this upper bound).  The maximum length of the pairing queue is the `diff.renameLimit` setting.

The default value for this was originally 100, then raised to 200 in 2008 ([commit `50705915eae8`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50705915eae89eae490dff30fa370ed02e4d6e72), Git version 1.5.6), then to 400 in 2011 ([commit `92c57e5c1d29`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92c57e5c1d29db96a927e2a713c5aa4ae99ce749), Git version 1.7.5).  It probably deserves another doubling by now, but if your Git is at least 1.7.5, committing 400 such renames at a time will preserve rename-finding across individual commits.

Note, however, that this depends on Git examining *adjacent* commits, so that there are only 400 such changes in the tree.  If you skip directly from an early version to a late version—as, e.g., happens during `git merge`, or if you `git diff` an early tag against a late tag—the number of unpaired file names may be much larger and hence overflow the pairing queues.  The queue lengths for `git merge` are larger by default but are still not 3000.

You can configure higher rename detection thresholds.  Setting `diff.renameLimit` to zero means "use the maximum possible": not quite *no* limit, but as close as Git can get.

Comment: Thanks for those insights. In my case, merges across the code reorg will be rare. How about 'git annotate'. Will it work fine as long as the number of renamed files in each commit is less than `diff.renameLimit`?

Comment: Git's annotate / blame walks back one revision at a time, like `git log --follow` or `git diff` of parent-vs-child, so it should be fine. It has its own more complex algorithms so it might not be exactly the same: in particular, it looks (if so directed) for individual lines moved or copied from one file to another, which `git diff` does not. So it should find *more* instances, not fewer.